# jquery - slidetoggle function on sliding out

Tags: jquery

My question is, how can I do something when the slideToggle function is called "up" (sliding back up/hiding)?

```
    $('#achs').click(function() {
         $('#ach').slideToggle(function() {

//When slideToggle is going to hide, I wish to addCss to something else. 

            });
        $('#ach').addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: just add `$('#ach').addClass('active');` inside the slideToggle function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#achs').click(function() {
    $('#ach').slideToggle(function() {
         if($("#ach").is(":visible")) {
            // do something
         }
    });
    $('#ach').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add CSS when the element is *about* to slide up, not when it has *finished* sliding up, you can use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector before calling `slideToggle()`:

```
$("#achs").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(":visible")) {
        // Add CSS to something else...
    }
    $this.slideToggle().addClass("active");
});
```

If you want the CSS to be added when the element has *finished* sliding up, you can rely on the callback function passed to `slideToggle()` and test with the [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector (because the element will be hidden at the end of the animation, before the callback is invoked):

```
$("#achs").click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
            // Add CSS to something else...
        }
    }).addClass("active");
});
```